# Rails 4.1.4 Custom Confirmation Alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using **Rails 4.1.4** in my app. I have a link to a *delete* method which has the *data-confirm* attribute so a confirmation dialog appears before continuing with the action.

```
<%= link_to t(:delete_account), delete_account_path, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm", data: { confirm: t(:delete_account_confirmation_text) } %>
```

The confirmation dialog that appears is the browser's default. How can I customize this to use **Bootstrap** modal for example?.

Regards!!!.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using some custom coffeescript, like:

```
$ ->
  $.rails.allowAction = (link) ->
    return true unless link.attr('data-confirm')
    $.rails.showConfirmDialog(link) 
    false 

  $.rails.confirmed = (link) ->
    link.removeAttr('data-confirm')
    link.trigger('click.rails')

  $.rails.showConfirmDialog = (link) ->
    message = link.attr 'data-confirm'
    html = """
           <div class="modal" id="confirmationDialog">
             <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                   <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                   <h1>#{message}</h1>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                   <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">#{link.data('cancel')}</a>
                   <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary confirm">#{link.data('ok')}</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           """
    $(html).modal()
    $('#confirmationDialog .confirm').on 'click', -> $.rails.confirmed(link)
```

This also immediately allows to translate your ok and cancel buttons, like

```
data: { confirm: t('messages.confirm_delete'), ok: t('buttons.ok'), cancel: t('buttons.cancel')
```

If you don't always want to repeat this, use some helper to create a custom "delete link"!

Comment: Thanks!. But I'm not using coffeescript, how should I put it with javascript?. Where does this code goes?. Thanks for the help!!.

Comment: You can convert coffeescript to javascript using the "try coffeescript" section on http://coffeescript.org. You should put the resulting script in the app/assets/javascript folder. You can also put the script above in a .js.coffee file in the same folder. Rails will take care of the conversion!

Comment: You might want to  `$(html).modal().on 'hidden.bs.modal', -> $(@).remove()` to clean up the DOM detritus when `data-remote="true"`

Comment: Also consider renaming `data-confirm` value in `$.rails.confirmed` so you can restore it in `ajax:error`. If not, you'll end up with a delete link that no longer does a confirmation.

Comment: Thanks ! So useful. You made my day.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use a [gem (data-confirm-modal)](https://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal) for this.